# Time Complexity Difference between word break and Permutation

Tags: java, string, performance, dynamic, combinations

[Word Break - Recurrence](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/discuss/169383/The-Time-Complexity-of-The-Brute-Force-Method-Should-Be-O(2n)-and-Prove-It-Below)

The explanation in the above article makes sense. But why this cant be T(n) = nT(n-1) + 1? which results in n!. What am I doing wrong?

How is this different from permutation recursion, [Permutation - recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in `Permutation`, let's say we have a sequence of `a,b,c,d`, for the first step, we can choose all of them, which make our first step have `n` possibilities. After that, for the seconed step, we still have `n-1` possibilities for every first step. So we have `n*(n-1)...`.

Whileas in `Word Break`, as sad in the link, lest's say we have a sequence of `abcd` and we have a word list `a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,...`. We still have `n` choses for the first step: `a,ab,abc,abcd`. But after that, we don't have `n-1` choses for every first step. For instance, if we chose `abcd` as the first step, we don't have a second step at all.